# how to check if a number has dashes or gap between digits in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

how to check if a number has gaps or dashes per 4 digits? I have a programme with credit cards. credit card has 16 digits which can be :

`1234567890987612` or `1234-5678-1234-5678` or `1234 1234 5678 5678`.

if the credit card has only this form, programme must output true. can someone give me a fast and easy way? until now I did it:

`if len(creditcard)==16 and creditcard.isdigit()` ......

Comment: This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; what have **you tried**, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: you did not stop editing your post and adding new conditions... irksome.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a regular expression.  Look into the `regex` module.  I'm not very good at writing the most efficient possible regex, but the following expression would match a 16 digit numeric value with dashes separating groups of 4 numbers:

`[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}`

The following would match 16 digit numeric values with gaps between groups of 4

`[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}`

and the following would match a 16 digit numeric value with no gaps or spaces

`[0-9]{16}`

You'll use the `regex` module to compile these patterns, and then compare them against the input you receive to verify your input matches one of these patterns.  Expand on the patterns as necessary, and learn to write your own basic regular expressions - they're very useful for finding patterns in text :)

Edit: As mentioned in the comment, one can use \d to match all digits, instead of the `[0-9]{4}` method I used, you would write `\d{4}`.  Then, testing for boundaries ensures you don't match sequences longer than 16 digits.  The above examples will match on arbitrarily long sequences of digits, but this:
`\b\d{4}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}\b`
I believe will match only on a 16 digit sequence (the primary difference here being `\b` which matches a word boundary).

Comment: `print(re.match("[0-9]{16}","5"*50))` matches. However, a 50-digit number isn't a valid credit card number. And your regexes could be improved. Use `\d` in the first place. Python 3 is not the 1980 version of `sed`.

Comment: Yep, they can definitely be improved, especially by ensuring word boundaries around the 16 digits. Thanks.